# Generic override in swift extension not being called

Tags: swift, generics, overriding

I have a generic type

```
enum ResultState<T> {
    case found(T)
}
```

with a few extensions

```
extension ResultState {

    func hello() { print("Hello") }
}

extension ResultState where T: Collection {

    func hello() { print("Hello, collection") }
}
```

These work perfectly and exactly as I would expect them to:

```
ResultState.found(1).hello() // prints "Hello"
ResultState.found([1]).hello() // prints "Hello, collection"
```

However, if they are called from within another generic function it doesn't behave the same

```
func myFunction<T>(_ state: ResultState<T>) {
    state.hello()
}
```

For example,

```
myFunction(ResultState.found(1)) // prints "Hello"
myFunction(ResultState.found([1]) // prints "Hello"
```

Now, the basic version of hello is called each time, even though inspecting `T` inside `myFunction` shows it is definitely `Array<Int>`.

Is this expected Swift behaviour?

If so, how would I work around it - how can I get the correct version of `hello` called from within `myFunction`?

Comment: Its strange !!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the information is lost for myFunction and only applies one level down so to speak for ResultState. Not sure this is the solution you want but one way is to define different functions in the same way you have different extensions.

```
func myFunction<T: Collection>(_ state: ResultState<T>)  {
    state.hello()
}

func myFunction<T>(_ state: ResultState<T>)  {
    state.hello()
}
```

Executing

```
ResultState.found(1).hello() 
ResultState.found([1]).hello() 

myFunction(ResultState.found(1))
myFunction(ResultState.found([1]))
```

will yield

> Hello
>   Hello, collection
>   Hello
>   Hello, collection

Comment: Yea, annoyingly that's the only thing I could think of too :( I'm trying to not have multiple functions at the myFunction level in case I need to extend ResultState for other types of `T` - ideally I should be able to do that without having to touch any other code. Thanks for you help though :)